# Не получается сделать бесконечный слайдер

Tags: javascript, html, slider, swiper

Делаю слайдер через swiper js, нужно чтобы он сам прокручивался без остановки, но у меня получается какая-то фигня.

```
<section class="brands">
        <div class="container">
           <div class="brands__title"><?=$props['title']?></div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="brands__container swiper3">
            <div class="brands__items swiper-wrapper">
                <?php foreach ($list as $image) :?>
                <div class="brands__item swiper-slide">
                    <img src="<?=$image['photo']?>"alt="" class="brands__photo">
                </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
    
        </div>
    
  
    </section>
```

```
import Swiper from 'swiper';
import { Autoplay } from 'swiper/modules';
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/autoplay';


let swiper3 = new Swiper('.swiper3', {
    slidesPerView:'5.5',
    modules: [Autoplay],
    slidesPerColumn: 1,
    spaceBetween: 25,
    loop:true,




});
```

Comment: С формулировкой вопроса, у вас получилось не лучше.... Что имеено у вас происходит, что не так, как должно быть? Покажите код слайдера(JS) и финальную разметку HTML

Comment: Всм? И html и код слайдера в вопросе есть.

Answer (score 0):

Не понятно откуда `modules: [Autoplay]`

https://swiperjs.com/types/interfaces/types_modules_autoplay.AutoplayOptions
тут указано что конфиг должен выглядеть както так:

```
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
  autoplay: {
    delay: 5000,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  let swiper3 = new Swiper(".swiper3", {
    slidesPerView: 1,
    spaceBetween: 30,
    loop: true,
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
      clickable: true,
    },
    navigation: {
      nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
      prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
    },
  });
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]